# Ruby and Rails, what's the difference between == and === for ActiveRecord classes comparison?

Tags: ruby

I was doing some `case.. when..`  and I found this behaviour.

```
case vehicle.class
when Bike
  puts "This is a Bike"
when Car
  puts "This is a car"
else
  puts "May be it's an UFO."
  raise "ALIENS"
end
```

I found that, even though the variable `vehicle` is an instance of `Bike`, it didn't go through to produce the output "This is a bike". Instead, it raises an exception.

I find this peculiar because the following code outputs `It's a string`.

```
case "FooBar"
when String
  puts "It's a string"
else
  puts "It's not a string"
end
```

I tried in the live shell of `better_errors` and found the following.

```
>> vehicle.class
=> Vehicle(id:integer, name: string, … , updated_at: datetime)
>> Vehicle
=> Vehicle(id:integer, name: string, … , updated_at: date time)

>> vehicle.class == Vehicle
=> true
>> vehicle.class === Vehicle
=> false
```

Or does that have something to do with the `RACK_ENV`?

Answer (score 3):

If `vehicle` is an instance of `Bike`, then `Bike === vehicle` is `true`. On the other hand, `vehicle.class` is `Bike`, and hence `Bike === vehicle.class` is the same as `Bike === Bike`, which is `false` because the class of `Bike` is `Class`, which is not `Bike`.

Take off `class`.

```
case vehicle
when Bike
  puts "This is a Bike"
when Car
  puts "This is a car"
else
  puts "May be it's an UFO."
  raise "ALIENS"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`===` is used in `case` statements in the background, and tests if the right-side is a member of the class on the left-side. (Note that it is not commutative as a result.)

```
>> Fixnum === 2
=> true
>> class Vehicle; end
=> nil
>> class Truck < Vehicle; end
=> nil
>> Truck === Truck.new
=> true
>> Vehicle === Truck.new
=> true
>> Truck.new === Truck
=> false
```